# .htaccess breaking css when executing the internal redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

i have the following code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^releases/([a-z]*)/$ releases.php?go=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The way i access this is

```
domain.com/subdir/releases/data
```

This how ever gets the redirect done but it breaks all the css images js etc.

Could anyone suggest an alternate. Thnx

and i want to include the condition to check if file is releases.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/releases/(.*)$
```

would that work ? thnx

Comment: Use a `RewriteCond` to exclude css/etc. from rewriting. Or use `<base href=>` to reroute resource references in your html pages.

Comment: And what do you expect if you have unconditional `RewriteRule ^releases/([a-z]*)/$ releases.php?go=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`?

Comment: how exactly do i exclude all css and image formats in rewrite condition

Comment: well my condition would be only when the file name is releases.php...and its not a duplicate. ive checked it , didnt help

Comment: anyone any input is appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using relative paths. When doing rewrites I also suggest to use absolute URLs for js/css/images. I use absolute paths anyway but especially when using rewrites.

Use the full document path or use `/` in front of the files.

So if you have something like

```
<script src="yourscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Change it to this

```
<script src="/yourscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or just use the full path to the file and that would work too.